# Parcelable extension for Kotlin is not working as intended - throwing Exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-savedstate

I want to save my result from API inside `SavedStateHandle` for my `ViewModel`.
For this reason I made all of my data `Parcelable` to make this function.

Code:

```
@Parcelize
data class DataResult(
    val result: Result<List<MyData>>?,
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class MyData(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val phone: String,
    val photo: String? = null): Parcelable
class MyViewModel(savedState: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel(){

     val resultData = savedState.getLiveData<DataResult?>("resultData", null)
     ...
}
```

Getting exception when I minimize app and go to background:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = kotlin.Result)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.my.project.viewmodel.MyData
```

I just wrapped `Result` class in my own `Data class` and made it `Parcelable` just in case although `Result` class is `Serializable` by default so it should not be a problem at all.

Comment: A ViewModel keeps the data within it if its scope is not cleared, it survives through configuration changes or app cleared in background. `SavedStateHandle` is supposed to save the argument passing to the `View` and some View's temporary value. So why not just save the `List<MyData>` LiveData field in ViewModel instead of getting it from SavedStateHandle.
To me `SavedStateHandle` shouldn't save anything too complicated like this